# BigDecimal adding wrong value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a `BigDecimal` defined like this:

```
private static final BigDecimal sd = new BigDecimal(0.7d);
```

if i print it, i get the value:

```
0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

which causes some wrong calculations. Does anyone know a way to get the exact value of `0.7` as `BigDecimal`? Change it to `0.71` would view the right result, but it shouldn't be like that

Comment: Check the constructor logic with a  `Double`, you will understand the difficulties between this conversion ;)

Comment: thanks for all the answers, yet i don't really understand why the conversion fails. i thought i would only get wrong values with a double, if the number of digits exceed the precision. 0.7 should totally be 0.7 and `double d=0.7d;
  Float f=new Float(0.7);
  System.out.println(f);
  System.out.println(d);` prints exactly 0.7 in both cases.

Comment: `double d = 0.7d; ` don't store simply a value like `int = 0` `dec = 7` but use a mantissa logic that use exponents, the reverse logic is use to create the `BigDecimal`. The floating value precision lost occurs in that case

Comment: The conversion from source code to double is not precise. The conversion from (imprecise) double to BigDecimal is exact.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: it is clear you don't completely understand *binary* floating point types like `double` or `float`. Please take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html or, simpler, http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/ . That probably explains why `0.7` can never be represented exactly in such a format, but why e.g. `0.5`, `0.375`, `0.75` or even `0.0234375` (= 3/128) can.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: The value printed out is rounded by the display logic. `0.6999... etc.` is very close to `0.7`, so it is rounded to `0.7`. The Java display logic tries to display values such that the same value can be reproduced if converted to binary (floating point) again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a String literal:

```
private static final BigDecimal sd = new BigDecimal("0.7");
```

If you use a `double`, actually [`public BigDecimal(double val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) is called. The reason you do not get 0.7 is that it cannot be exactly represented by a `double`. See the linked JavaDoc for more information.

Comment: You're right. I mixed that up. Corrected in the anser.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you bothered to **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) you're using, you'd already know the answer.

> 3. When a `double` must be used as a source for a `BigDecimal`, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the `double` to a `String` using the [`Double.toString(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) method and then using the [`BigDecimal(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-) constructor. To get that result, use the `static` [`valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) method.

When you then look at the javadoc of [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-), you'll find:

> **Note:** This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a `BigDecimal` from the result of using [`Double.toString(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-).

**So there is your answer:** Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7d)`, not `new BigDecimal(0.7d)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the declared value in String literal such as `new BigDecimal("0.7");`

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways:

```
private static final BigDecimal sd = new BigDecimal("0.7");
private static final BigDecimal sd = new BigDecimal(0.7d, MathContext.DECIMAL32);
private static final BigDecimal sd = new BigDecimal(0.7d, MathContext.DECIMAL64)
```

Comment: How about `sd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7d);`, as also recommended by the javadoc?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best solution. Thx @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a `BigDecimal` from a `double` is surprisingly complicated. First, it can only be done via the detour of a string. (You can't get the constructor with `double` and a `MathContext` right. I've tried a lot. At the latest in cases in which the number of places before the decimal point would need to change due to rounding, it becomes difficult. Hence the warning in the Javadoc that you shouldn’t use it.)

However, even there, it is not enough with a simple `String.format()`, since `String.format()` is sensitive to the default `Locale` and outputs different decimal separators depending on system/VM settings, while the `BigDecimal` constructor always requires a dot as a decimal separator. So you have to construct your own `Formatter` with `Locale.US`. If you have this up and running, you will get a warning of an unclosed resource.

I found this to work:

```
static BigDecimal toBigDecimal(double value, int decimalPlaces) {
    String format = "%." + decimalPlaces + "f";
    try (Formatter formatter = new Formatter(Locale.US)) {
        String formatted = formatter.format(format, value).toString();
        return new BigDecimal(formatted);
    }
}
```